# How to check if a python varaible is of type pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python

In Python 3.x, how can I check if my variable is of type `pandas.core.series.Series`?

Comment: `type(variable) == pandas.core.series.Series` should return you `True`/`False` based on type

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `isinstance`:

```
s = pd.Series([2,3])

print (isinstance(s, pd.Series))
True
```

Comment: `isinstance(s, pd.Series)` will only work after running `import pandas as pd`.

Is there any good way to generalize your solution to the case where some other user imported pandas with something like `import pandas as pan` (rather than `pd`)? 

Or should I then add `import pandas as pd` within my function definition (first line after `def()...`)?

Comment: @RubenGeert - I think `import pandas as pd` is most common way, so if other user use `import pandas as pan` it will be not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(myvar, pandas.core.series.Series):
    # Do some processing
```

Comment: `if isinstance(pkl, pd.DataFrame) or isinstance(pkl, pd.Series):` seems to be sufficient